# How to pass Checkbox value 0 if not checked and 1 if checked using array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a checkbox when i selected i have on database the value '1' but when i dont select i have this erreur 
{SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'actif' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `techniciens` (`user_id`, `actif`, `moyenne_avis`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (6, , 30.555, 2018-03-14 09:07:15, 2018-03-14 09:07:15))}

create.blade.php

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <ul>
      @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
         <li>{{$message}}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
     </div>
    @endif
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Ajouter Technicien</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('technicien')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" 
 value="{{ old('nom')   
            }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('nom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('nom') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="prenom" value="{{ 
          old('prenom') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('prenom'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('prenom') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Telephone</label>
                <input id="tel" type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" 
value="{{ old('tel') }}" 
        required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('tel'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('tel') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mobile</label>
                <input id="mobil" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="mobil" value="{{ 
      old('mobil') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('mobile'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mobil') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Role</label>
                <input id="role" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="role" value="{{ old('role') }}" 
     required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('role'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : 
 '' }}">
                <label for="">E-Mail Address</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="email" value="{{ 
   old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}
 </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Password</label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password" type="password" 
 class="form-control" 
     name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}
  </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="password_confirmation" 
 type="password" class="form-control" 
    name="password" value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}" required 
 autofocus>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zoneintervention">zoneintervention</label>
                <select multiple name="zoneintervention_id[]" 
   id="zoneintervention" class="form-
    control" >

                        @foreach($zoneintervention as $zoneintervention)
                         <option value="{{ $zoneintervention->id }}">
                            {{$zoneintervention->code_postal}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Moyenne Avis</label>
                 <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-
  control"value="
    {{old('moyenne_avis')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name ="actif" value="1">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "suivant" class="form-control 
 btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

controler

```
 public function create()
 {
     $zoneintervention = Zoneintervention::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $metier = metier::orderBy('libelle_metier', 'desc')->get();
    $tache = tache::orderBy('libelle_tache', 'desc')->get();
    $user = user::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('technicien.create')->with('zoneintervention', 
   $zoneintervention)->with('user', 
    $user);

  }
  /**
  * Store a newly created resource in storage.
  *
     * @param  
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $user = new user();
    $user->nom = $request->input('nom');
    $user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
    $user->tel = $request->input('tel');
    $user->mobil = $request->input('mobil');
    $user->role = $request->input('role');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();

    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien->user_id = $user->id;
    $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
    $technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien->save();
    $technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request->zoneintervention_id);



    return redirect('tarification/create');

}
```

route.php

```
Route::get('/technicien', 'TechnicienController@index');
Route::get('/technicien/create', 'TechnicienController@create');
Route::post('/technicien', 'TechnicienController@store');
```

Comment: You have defined `actif` fillable in your `protected $fillable = ["actif"];` Remove it from there and and add it as a `nullable()` in migration it fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$request->has()`

```
$technicien = new technicien();
$technicien->user_id = $user->id;
if($request->has('actif')){
       $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
}else{
       $technicien->actif = 0;
}
$technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
$technicien->save();
```

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"

Comment: @chagou2704 glad it helps:)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add hidden input with zero value, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="actif" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="actif" value="1">
```

So if checkbox is checked, then `actif` value will be 1, if checkbox is unchecked, then `actif` value will be 0, because then hidden value will be used.

Comment: when i use this solution i can choose the 2 checkboxes and it does not make sense

Comment: 2 checkboxes? One input is not checkbox, it's input with type hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It's an SQLSTATE[23000] Integrity constraint violation error which occurs if the rules you declared in migration file doesn't matches with the input from your form. So in order to resolve this error you need to just add **nullable()** to your database migration file where you have **'actif'** column declared in the up method.

```
$table->tinyInteger('actif')->nullable();
```

Comment: show your database migration file.. I will edit my answer likewise.